# PHP If statement html option value 0

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, select-options

So I have a button on my website that lets people add game categories to a profile, I dont what the user to be able to click add to profile unless something is selected in the dropdown. I have tried a few things but I'm see the results I want, this is the form block of code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-md-3 control-label">Game Categories *</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select name="game_categories_id" id="game_categories_id" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select One...</option>
                <?php foreach ($game_categories as $game_category): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $game_category->ID; ?>">
                        <?php echo $game_category->name; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And down in the my submit area I have the following:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <?php if (!empty($_POST['game_categories_id']) && ($_POST['game_categories_id'] == 0))  { ?>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_game_categories_id" ?>">Add Game</button>
   <?php } elseif (!empty($_POST['credit_reporting_org_id']) && ($_POST['credit_reporting_org_id'] != 0)) { ?>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled id="save_game_categories_id" ?>">Add Game</button>
<?php } ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

What I want to happen is that the Add Game button is not clickable until they select something in the dropdown, but right now nothing is showing besides the close button.

Also I have this in a js file that deals with adding game categories:

```
// Save game categories
$('#modal').on('click', '#save_game_categories_id', function() {
    var errors = 0;
    var $form = $('#add_game_categories_form');

    // Make sure game fields are filled
    $.each([$('#game_categories_id'), $('#game_type_id')], function(i, $input) {
        if ($input.val() == '' || $input.val() == 0) {
            $input.parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            errors++;
        } else {
            $input.parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

    if (errors > 0) return false; // Don't proceed if there are errors

    $.post('/game/approved_game/' + game_topic_id, $form.serialize(), function(
        data
    ) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            refresh_approved_game();
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
        } else {
            $form.find('.alert').show();
        }
    });
});
```

So I have the js already and I know it works as Im able to add games, but I just want to be able to disable the submit button if they dint select anything in the dropdown

Comment: It seems that you're going to use javascript.

Comment: Why are you checking `$_POST['game_categories_id'] == 0`? Also is the second html on another page right? Because otherwise you cannot change on real-time without using javascript.

Comment: In Jquery, something like this `$('#save_game_categories_id').click(function(e){ if($('#game_categories_id > option:selected').size() == 0) e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: So no way to do it without JS

Answer (score 1):

You might want to accomplish this with some Javascript. You can use Jquery like this:

```
$('#game_categories_id').on('change', function(){
  var noAnswer = ($(this).val() == 0);
  $('#save_game_categories_id').attr('disabled', noAnswer);
});
```

If you need to use Vanilla JS, I can add a solution in that too.

Comment: So no way to do it without JS

Comment: You can do it in PHP, but that will require a page reload just to do some simple validation. If you want to do it in PHP, you will have to allow the user to submit the form and reload the page and then on the reload, disable the button, then have the user submit again.

Comment: So I have the above JS in another file but I still not able to get it, maybe Im not calling it correctly

Comment: @LookingToHelp Open your browser's developer console and look at the console pane to see if any Javascript errors are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['game_categories_id']) && ($_POST['game_categories_id'] == 0))  { ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['game_categories_id']) && ($_POST['game_categories_id'] != 0))  { ?>
```

So that the user adds a game when something is selected.

Answer (score -1):

as far as i understand attaching example code below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" <?php if(userSelectedCategory == ''){ echo'disabled';} ?> id="save_game_categories_id" ?>">Add Game</button>
```

this will disabled you button if didn't select any category other wise remove **disabled attribute** which means add game button is **enabled**

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does that code disable a button, and enable it once something is selected?

Comment: @NicoHaase i just gave him a example, the reason i didn't gave him full code because i dont want to confuse him, maybe he knows other method to do.

Comment: So, you've edited your answer completely now, and now it contains PHP code with syntax errors - I don't think that this is helpful to the OP

Comment: I dont know other methods beside JS to achieve this, but I dont really want to use JS, im not really following the code above through as I dont follow if(userSelectedCategory == ''){ echo'disabled';}